# Exporting Dataset to a xml file giving error in DBunit

Tags: java, dbunit

Hi all i'm working using dbunit. I'm trying to export datset of db into a xml file.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection;
import org.dbunit.database.IDatabaseConnection;
import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class DatabaseExport

{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
        Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://172.26.37.113:1433;DatabaseName=def_config","sqladmin_","halloween$2004");
        IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection( jdbcConnection );
       // full database export
        IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"));

    }
}
```

But it gives an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:323)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseTableIterator.getTable(DatabaseTableIterator.java:89)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.stream.DataSetProducerAdapter.produce(DataSetProducerAdapter.java:83)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlWriter.write(FlatXmlWriter.java:124)
    at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet.write(FlatXmlDataSet.java:378)
    at DatabaseExport.main(DatabaseExport.java:23)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:775)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:611)
    at org.dbunit.database.AbstractResultSetTable.<init>(AbstractResultSetTable.java:110)
    at org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.<init>(ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.java:59)
    at org.dbunit.database.CachedResultSetTableFactory.createTable(CachedResultSetTableFactory.java:60)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:319)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Please provide with the full.xml here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you have a table called `user` in your database. But `user` is a reserved keyword in MSSQL. DBUnit creates some query like:

```
SELECT * FROM user;
```

But this creates the error you are seeing. Instead DBUnit has to create a query like:

```
SELECT * from [user];
```

I think you could fix this using the [Escape pattern](http://www.dbunit.org/properties.html#escapepattern) configuration setting of DBUnit. I didn't try this myself but something like this should work:

```
connection.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_ESCAPE_PATTERN , "[?]");
```

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for above solution. That is the actual solution.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConfig;
import org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection;
import org.dbunit.database.IDatabaseConnection;
import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class DatabaseExport
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
        Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=def_config","user","passwd$2004");
        IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection( jdbcConnection );
        connection.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_ESCAPE_PATTERN , "[?]");
        // full database export
        IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("C:/full.xml"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export the dataset usnig ant we can do like this

`<dbunit driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=config1"
                    userid="user"
                    password="passwd$2004"
                    escapePattern="[?]"
                    datatypeFactory="org.dbunit.ext.mssql.MsSqlDataTypeFactory">

                <compare src="C:/export.xml"/>
            </dbunit>`