# Spring Test DBUnit and table schema name

Tags: java, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

Is it possible to set the table schema name when using `@DatabaseSetup` annotation from  Spring Test DBUnit? Currently I'm using it like this:

```
@DatabaseSetup("user-data.xml")
public class UserMapperTest {
}
```

user-data.xml: (I also tried to set the element name to user.system_user without any luck)

```
<dataset>
    <system_user
        ...
        />
</dataset>
```

And here I'm creating my table with schema called user:

```
create table "user".system_user (...);
```

And this is the exception that I get when  running test:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SYSTEM_USER" not found; SQL statement:
delete from SYSTEM_USER [42102-175]
```

Answer (score 3):

I used this trick.
First, we need OracleConnection bean:

```
<bean id="oracleConnection" class="org.dbunit.ext.oracle.OracleConnection">
    <constructor-arg value="#{dataSource.getConnection()}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="<your_scheme_name>"/>
</bean>
```

Then you can use this annotation in your methods

```
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection = "oracleConnection")
@DatabaseSetup(...)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [spring-test-dbunit](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/) then you need to create an IDatabaseConnection with a specific DBUnit configuration. Following the doc's example I've setup this one for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
">
    <bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
        <property name="datatypeFactory">
            <bean class="org.dbunit.ext.postgresql.PostgresqlDataTypeFactory" />
        </property>
        <!--property name="qualifiedTableNames" value="true" /-->
        <property name="caseSensitiveTableNames" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConnection" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="databaseConfig" ref="dbUnitDatabaseConfig"/>
        <property name="schema" value="sapeo"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I needed to use
    <property name="qualifiedTableNames" value="true"/>
because the data in my .xml file was qualified with the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. You cannot with the annotation however you can specify the schema on the connection string. Here is how I solved my case:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:fullywallet;MVCC=true" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>your.package.to.be.scanned</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">public</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my case I was using HSQLDB but it is applicable for other databases as well